# How to Learn Solidity

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapp-development

I know basic solidity but how i learn higher level solidity to make dapps ?
What advance skill required for smart contract and Dapps development ?
Where I can practice my skills ?
Please Help Me. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to work through the tutorials of https://cryptozombies.io . It's an interactive development tutorial. If you feel like that's some stuff your already master, head over to https://solidity.readthedocs.io and learn "solidity in depth". Set yourself some tasks to exercise (smart contract, backend, frontend) and implement. Choose tasks for which you don't immediately know the solution, but have the feeling that it is realizable. Be creative. You can also take some inspiration from complex concepts which already have been released, just search the web. OpenZeppelin offers some complex concepts, like upgradable smart contracts: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin . Have fun.

Answer (score 2):

I teach the Ethereum bootcamp at B9lab. https://academy.b9lab.com. It has a very serious certification exam. You will pass it if you're serious because we will help you.

Hope it helps.